# Retrofit JSONAPI converter needed?

Tags: java, android, converters, retrofit, json-api

Is there some way to use the JSONAPI spec with Retrofit?, don't know how this will work or how to start, any help?.

I found this gist: https://gist.github.com/Gregadeaux/cbcc3781fda9d7fa6498, it uses RxJava and some other libraries.

Also, is a converter needed?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/jasminb/jsonapi-converter is what you're looking for

from the docs

```
// Create object mapper
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Set serialisation/deserialisation options if needed (property naming strategy, etc...)

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://yourapi")
        .addConverterFactory(new JSONAPIConverterFactory(objectMapper, Book.class, Author.class))
        .build();

// Create service using service interface
MyBooksService booksService = retrofit.create(MyBooksService.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

retrofit provide [list](http://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration) of existed JSON converters, also you can implements [`Converter.Factory`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/Converter.java) interface and provide your own converter. Then you can pass your class in an instance when building your adapter.

***Related resources***:

1. [Retrofit — Define a Custom Response Converter](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-replace-the-integrated-json-converter/)